# How do I resolve HTTP Error 404.8?

Tags: xml, flash, webserver

We recently moved servers and now the flash that did work at one time does not work because it doesn't recognize the xml files. Here is the error in detail:

```
Server Error in Application

Internet Information Services 7.5 Error Summary HTTP Error 404.8 - Not Found The request filtering module is configured to deny a path in the URL that contains a hiddenSegment section. Detailed Error Information ModuleRequestFilteringModule NotificationBeginRequest HandlerStaticFile Error Code0x00000000 Requested URLhttp://obscured.xml Physical PathD:\home\obscured.xml Logon MethodNot yet determined Logon UserNot yet determined
```

Answer (score 33):

The issue is caused by IIS protecting the file you are requesting.

IIS by default sets a filter to deny requests to files with certain names such as `app_data`, `bin` etc to protect web applications.  This is done via the hidden segments control in IIS.  Your app seems to be affected by this.

Ideally you should change the name of the file you are requesting.

However, if you cannot do so then see the [article here](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/hiddensegments) for steps on how to remove it.

Answer (score 11):

In my case, I had an application that had a business object called a bin. Can you guess what happened? The url for my BinController was http://localhost:6537/bin/index

Clearly, RequestFiltering had an entry denying access to the bin folder, so the request was blocked before it even got to the MVC routing engine.

I simply renamed my controller to BinsController and http://localhost:6537/bins/index  worked just fine.

Comment: same thing happens